# How do https stacks handle failed links when there are multiple A records?

Tags: networking, https, failover

I have setup DNS entries so that a certain FQDN has four A records, with four IPv4 addresses of four networks boxes converging thru a router to a single https server. That does load balancing across the boxes.

I'm worried about what happens if a network box goes down. The DNS resolution mechanism will return IPv4 addresses even if the link is down. I read [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10927/using-multiple-a-records-for-my-domain-do-web-browsers-ever-try-more-than-one) that (trimmed)

> pretty much every browser receive the full list of A records, and check others if the one it is using fails.

which is fine. But my server provides a web service: it's clients are typically not web browsers. I know one uses libcurl under Linux Centos 7, but there could be others.

How would various https stacks (including but not limited to the above) handle a failed link (as in network box powered down or its line severed)?

Comment: What do you mean by failed link?  Do  you mean the server is completely down and not responding,  Or the server is up and returning 5**/4** errors.

Answer (score 0):

Any application querying DNS records receives all the results. How they are handled depends on the application, it can try the first, a fixed number, or all of them.

Most applications should try all records, but if it is important to you, you should verify yourself. Just setup a DNS name that points to some addresses that don't respond, then try to access that name and see how many of the addresses are tried, andhow long the timeout is.